# How to change scenes on collision in C#, script isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it so when a player hits a box, it goes to the next scene. But I don't know how I would do that since this script isn't working.

Can anyone help? There are no stated errors.

Here's the script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Block")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("2");
    }
}
```

I don't recognize the problem, can anyone help?

Comment: This makes no sense without more context. You probably need another tag at least. Is it Unity?

Comment: Yes it's unity.

Answer (score 1):

Application.LoadLevel is obsolete, use SceneManager.LoadScene. Are you sure the name of the scene is 2, or is that the build index?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

...

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Block")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("SceneName");
        //Or:
        //SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneIndex); //(without these: ", because it's a number - an int, not a string)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for writing it in an answer, can't comment yet. Are you sure that code segment gets executed? Add " Debug.LogError("Positive"); " after the opening bracket. Also, are you sure the scene you are trying to load exists? Trying to load a scene named 2 is kinda suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Check the build settings menu and make sure your scene has been added to the build.

[More info on Build Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html)